# How can I coumpute Policy Gradient LOSS in tensorflow

Tags: reinforcement-learning, tensorflow, policy-gradient

I am self-studying RL and currently doing hw2 from Berkeley CS294-112. The thing I cannot figure out is how to compute loss in policy gradients. Basically, REINFORCE algorithm has the following update process:

[image]

I thought I need to sum up log probability and reward for a single episode (time t=1 ... t=T) then multiply them, which means

[image]

And for all episodes (i=1, ..., i=N) I tried to compute "MEAN". Most of codes in github, however, do differently:

```py
with tf.variable_scope("log_probability_weighted_by_advantage"):
   sy_weighted_logprob_n = tf.multiply(self.sy_logprob_n, self.sy_adv_n)

with tf.variable_scope("loss"):
   self.sy_loss = - tf.reduce_mean(sy_weighted_logprob_n)

self.update_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.learning_rate).minimize(self.sy_loss)
```

In this code, sy_logprob_n and sy_adv_n have **[total # of states from all the episode N, 1]** shape. So how I understand this code is that do not care about summing up and multiplying "for a single episode", but rather multiplying each states of all the episodes and sum them up(or compute mean).

And why does this works?

Comment: Pseudocode in the image seems weird to me, typically $\nabla_{\theta} \log \pi_{\theta} (a_t|s_t)$ and $r(s_t, a_t)$ should be under the same sum, not 2 separate sums, so the github code should be correct.

Comment: @Brale_ The image is from berkeley CS294 lecture note. In David Silver's lecture note, he mentioned that "Consider a simple class of one-step MDPs" when he derived REINFORCE. According to this, I could accept that the github code is correct if we consider only one step for each states.